# invalid use of void expression in context of c++ std::function

Tags: c++, callback, std-function

In below code snippet while calling call back function "Invalid use of void expression" error
is flashed by the compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
template<class type>
class State {
public:
State(type type1,const std::function<void (type type1 )> Callback)
 {

 }

};

template <class type>
void Callback(type type1 )
{
  //Based on type validation will be done here
}

 int main()
 {
  State<int> obj(10,Callback(10));
  return 0;
}
```

Just want to know what is the wrong here so that same can be addressed .

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error message from your compiler?

Comment: error: invalid use of void expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to pass the `Callback<int>` function itself, not its return value (which there is none), to the constructor of `obj`. So do just that:

```
State<int> obj(10, Callback<int>);
```

Your current code actually *calls* `Callback(10)` first and then tries to take its `void` "return value" to pass it to the constructor of `obj`. Passing `void` is not allowed in C++, which is why the compiler is complaining. (`Callback(10)` is the "*void expresson*" here.)

Comment: Thanks for  your solution.It compiles fine but looks like doesn't hit the function as when i tried to print inside callback function it doesn't  appear on the screen.

Comment: @user2997518 did you actually call the function in the constructor? `Callback(type1);`

Comment: Yes it works now fine after calling inside constructor. Accepted your solution.

Comment: Accepted . you may see now green mark over there 

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
template<class type>
class State {
public:
State(type type1,const std::function<void (type)> callback)
 {
    callback(type1);
 }

};

template <class type>
void Callback(type type1 )
{

}

 int main()
 {
  State<int> obj(10, Callback<int>);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to go with lambda expression approach to avoid the confusion :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
template<class type>
class State 
{
public:
State( type type1, const std::function<void (type type1 )> Callback)

    {
        Callback(type1);
    }
};

int main()
{

 State<int > monitor(10,[] ( int fault) {std::cout<<"Any Message"; });
 return 0;

}
```