# Error: invalid use of void expression in parameter

Tags: c++

I have the objective to have my loop function repeated every 1000ms thanks to the timer_start function.

But everything does not go as planned :

> g++ -DDMP_FIFO_RATE=9 -Wall -g -O2   -c -o demo_raw.o demo_raw.cpp
>   demo_raw.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: demo_raw.cpp:66:33: error:
>   invalid use of void expression
>            timer_start(loop(), 1000);
>                                    ^ make: *** [: demo_raw.o] Error 1
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 26s)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

MPU6050 accelgyro;

int16_t ax, ay, az;
int16_t gx, gy, gz;

void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}

void loop() 
{
    accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);
    printf("ax: %6hd\tay: %6hd\taz: %6hd\ngx: %6hd\tgy: %6hd\tgz: %6hd\n\n\n",ax,ay,az,gx,gy,gz);   
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    for (;;) 
        timer_start(loop(), 1000); 
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It seems you mean timer_start(loop, 1000);  instead of timer_start(loop(), 1000);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid use of void expression in context of c++ std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646851/invalid-use-of-void-expression-in-context-of-c-stdfunction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
timer_start(loop(), 1000);
```

You are passing the *return value* of `loop` as the first argument to `timer_start`. But `loop` returns `void` (aka *nothing*) so that doesn't make any sense.

You probably wanted to pass the function instead of the result of calling it, as in

```
timer_start(loop, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `timer_start` expects an *actual function* as its first parameter, not the value returned by a *call* to that function (as will be the case with your included `()`).

Just remove those parentheses:

```
int main()
{
    setup();
    for (;;) 
        timer_start(loop, 1000); 
}
```